# Linux vanilla kernel on QEMU and networking with eth0

Tags: linux, qemu, nat, ifconfig

I have downloaded and compiled vanilla linux kernel (3.7.1)
I used busybox for ramdisk then I booted it using QEMU. 
This is my QEMU command line

```
qemu-system-i386 -kernel bzImage -initrd ramdisk.img -append "root=/dev/ram rw console=ttyS0 rdinit=/bin/ash" -nographic -net nic -net user
```

everything goes well.
However, I can't use networking on vanilla kernel with busybox.

'ifup eth0' tells me

```
/ # ifup eth0
ip: SIOCGIFFLAGS: No such device
```

I googled the Internet but can' get any clue...
some advice would be nice
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably there is no driver (in your example is should be e1000) loaded or the device has another name.

In /sys/class/net/ you should find a listing of all available net-devices.
If there is none (besides lo) the driver is not loaded.

In qemu monitor type "info pci" and it will show you the PCI-address of your ethernet card. It should look like this:

```
...
Bus  0, device   3, function 0:
  Ethernet controller: PCI device 8086:100e
...
```

This device corresponds to /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/. 
The files "vendor" and "device" must contain "0x8086" and "0x100e" which is the PCI-id from above and by which the kernel determines the driver to load.

Try to load it manually with "modprobe e1000" or insmod. If loaded there must be a symlink named "driver". If not "dmesg" should give you the reason why not.