# My newly compiled kernel loses Networking in qemu

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, kernel, qemu

I compiled a kernel from source :
`make defconfig`
`make kvmconfig`
`make -j 4`
After this , i use the resulting bzImage for my qemu command:

`qemu-system-x86_64 -hda debian.img -kernel bzImage -append "root=/dev/sda console=ttyS0" -nographic -m 4096 -smp 2 --enable-kvm -net user,hostfwd=tcp::10021-:22 -net nic`

It mounts, and I get a shell and everything, but it loses connectivity. In qemu, it logs :

`[FAILED] Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
See 'systemctl status networking.service' for details.`

Can someone guide me on this ? I already consulted [Linux vanilla kernel on QEMU and networking with eth0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444903/linux-vanilla-kernel-on-qemu-and-networking-with-eth0) but it does not solve my issue. Also, Im not looking for hardcore qemu-bridge-solutions. Im pretty sure some network drivers are not getting loaded , but I can't figure out how to resolve it. Or maybe Im missing some kernel .config options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a user socket. For this qemu creates a regular socket in its host process and forwards the packets for specific ports in your guest machine to the host socket. It is doable but I find it annoying.

I always prefer creating a tap device and bridging it to my physical interface with these QEMU switches:

```
-netdev tap,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no,id=my_net_id \
-device driver=virtio-net,netdev=my_net_id
```

This way you have full network capabilities and you don't need to use some weird port redirection.

Comment: Many thanks, while I did not actually use this technique, I googled about it, and how to setup tap0 on bridge, and came across a command called "dhclient", apparently running it allows the vm to reconnect to the network drivers (probably) , and it ups the network interface .

Answer (score 2):

Was looking for an answer to this problem. For anyone else looking for help, the dhclient command OP refers to is (found [here](https://gist.github.com/extremecoders-re/e8fd8a67a515fee0c873dcafc81d811c)):

```
dhclient -v <interface>
```

where interface is whatever network adaptor shows up in the `ip a` results.

To make this change persist after reboot, I modified the /etc/network/interfaces file by inserting the following:

```
auto <interface>
iface <interface> inet dhcp
```

Comment: This works for the problem which I was facing. Is there a way to persist this configuration across reboots?

Comment: Updated answer with how to persist after reboot.